# Getting 'could not load file or assembly' error in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: .net-core, dll, class-library

I am getting the below error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.OracleClient, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

What I did:

1. Created new project in .NET Core 2.0.
2. Added project reference of class library built out in .Net framework 4.6.1.
3. Access function from class library which is using System.Data.OracleClient for database connection.
4. But it's failing while invoking function with above error.

How do we support accessing old .NET libraries built out earlier with lot of internal references in .NET Core project?

Comment: You can think about migrating of your project and switching to https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.OracleClient/ for .NET standard 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot.

Your project built with .NET Core must have only libraries built for .NET Core. You can't use the one built for .NET Framework.

Here is a quote from the book ASP.NET Core in Action when deciding to develop with .NET Core rather than .NET Framework:

> The largest obstacle you’re likely to come across is a third-party
> library holding you back, either because they only support older
> ASP.NET features, or they haven’t been converted to work with .NET
> Core yet.

Comment: @dnyandeo-narkhede This answer should be marked as answer to your question. It  is impossible to directly reference .NET Framework DLL/libraries from any .NET Core libraries.

Comment: @DnyandeoNarkhede in StackOverflow, when an answer is the one you need, you can select it as "the answer" so that it appears with a green check next to it